# HTTP error on ystockquote

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to fix an old script that I have made with Python 2.7. I've already adjusted the syntax for Python 3 but I'm not able to download stock quotes by using the module ystockquote (HTTPError: HTTP Error 502: notresolvable):

```
import ystockquote
#Function for taking the sample of Close prices:
def close_prices(symbol, start_date, close_date):
    data = ystockquote.get_historical_prices(symbol,start_date, close_date)
    sample = []

for date in data:
    # print data[date]['Close']
    sample.append(float(data[date]['Close']))

return sample
```

Thank you in advance